# Return object value method not working properly

Tags: java

I have a simple java method where i pass in an ArrayList of custom objects, and get their value, add them together and return them. I tried iterating with a foreach loop and a traditional loop, but it just returns 0.

```
public static int samletBeløb(ArrayList<Bruger> brugere) {
    int samletBeløb = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < brugere.size(); i++) {
        Bruger bruger =brugere.get(i);
        int value = bruger.getBeløbGivet();
        value += samletBeløb;
    }

    return samletBeløb;
}
```

I have made sure, that the Object values are not null, and when i debugged the program it looped through properly, however no value was added.

Comment: Please, don't use special characters in the variable names, such as `ø`. I recommend you to stick with the English naming.

Comment: show up your bruger class!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not changing the `samletBeløb` variable.

Change your code to:

```
public static int samletBeløb(ArrayList<Bruger> brugere) 
{
    int samletBeløb = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < brugere.size(); i++) {
        samletBeløb += brugere.get(i).getBeløbGivet();
    }

    return samletBeløb;
}
```

BTW, using Java 8 `Stream`s can reduce this method to a single line:

```
public static int samletBeløb(ArrayList<Bruger> brugere) 
{
    return brugere.stream().mapToInt(Bruger::getBeløbGivet).sum();
}
```

Comment: Is using streams best practise, when looping through objects like this?

Comment: @kristheman Once you get used to the syntax, using streams can make your code shorter and more readable, but It's a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are not adding each `value` to `samletBeløb` variable.
Change your code to:

```
public static int samletBeløb(ArrayList<Bruger> brugere) {
        int samletBeløb = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < brugere.size(); i++) {
            Bruger bruger =brugere.get(i);
            int value = bruger.getBeløbGivet();
            samletBeløb += value;
        }

        return samletBeløb;
}
```

Comment: Instead of Iterating each item stream API had some better solution to do the same task. As per your suggestion for loop iterating n time and n time var value init so n*n time complexity. So batter to use stream API like brugere.stream().mapToInt(Bruger::getBeløbGivet).sum();

Answer (score 2):

It because you are adding up in value but returning samletBeløbalways which is initialised as 0 so iits giving you always a 0; try this code:

```
public static int samletBeløb(ArrayList<Bruger> brugere) {
    int value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < brugere.size(); i++) {
        Bruger bruger =brugere.get(i);
          value += brugere.get(i).getBeløbGivet();

    }

    return value;
}
```